# Any reason for non-continuous mountain road barrier?

Tags: safety, road

I have been cycling recently in Polish mountains and when riding through one of less occupied mountain roads, I have found many places where road barrier (that is suppose to secure bikers and car drivers from falling into nearby river) is not continuous.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Some questions around:

1. Is anyone familiar of those? Can these be found in other countries?
2. Is there any particular reason for having such risky solution?
3. What am I missing in thinking that they pose a serious danger?

I was a too-close (as for me) from not stopping before one of these "separation holes" and falling into river, so I'd like to learn as much as possible about these "things".

Comment: It allows wildlife through.

Comment: Easier snow removal?

Comment: @DanielRHicks interesting thought, here in Finland we have fences to keep wildlife away from roads.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not cycling specific

Comment: I've seen plenty of similar roads with no barrier at all, or a barrier only on bends - luckily mainly when driving.

Comment: I'd suggest you raise a complaint with the local authority for this road. If there is a reason for it they should give you one. There's a global push for cycling atm so this should hopefully mean that your complaint gets some attention.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'd argue it's a good question, it's not "specific" or "exclusive" to cycling, but it's highly relevant. A car is too wide to go through one of these gaps and has a good chance of stopping against the end of a barrier. It could be argued that a cyclist has more risk of falling through the gap. And as for the actual purpose of them, I reckon it could be to leave a "refuge" of sort (not great but better than none) for pedestrians. I'm sure the UK has some detailed standards for how such roads should be dealt with.

Comment: Quite dangerous to me. A car or worse, a motorcyclist could be properly impaled by this. A cyclist missing his turn as well.

Comment: Steel is expensive?

Comment: Motorbikers are usually better off falling into the river. At the speeds their crashes happen they may get dismembered by these barriers. I'm close to argue that if a cyclist gets carried into these barriers they must be so fast that they also are more likely to get killed by the barrier than by the drop. It doesn't look like a difficult descent.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and support. After browsing all comments I tend to agree that (a) the actual answer is that these holes are for easier snow removal (they cannot be for helping wildlife to pass, because, as you see there is a fall down to the river, approx. 3-4 meters down on the other side), (b) this poses a serious security issue for bike riders and moto drivers, but -- the most important -- (c) this question is not for this site and is off-topic here. I was more than sure that I'll close or even delete it myself, but there are only 2 VTCs and 5 up-votes, which puzzles me.

Comment: I know this might not be a very educated guess, but any chance it could be that there was a car crash that damaged the barrier and it's waiting on a replacement? I'm from Poland and live in the UK, but would argue that Poland still has a much road standard than over here on the isles.

Comment: looking at the ends, this is not damage - it is deliberate.

Comment: @trejder I think it is relevant. We consider cycling infrastructure or aspects of roads that are dangerous to cyclists. The way the question is asked may not be quite on topic, but that is nitpicking. The gist of it is safety. And understanding the reason why something was done will help to lobby for improvement. *Up*, not close.

Comment: Agree, I upvoted and didn't vote to close. Cyclists are road users and this is a road feature, understanding why it's there helps a cyclist understand how to use the road safely, perhaps one shouldn't ride as close to the edge on this road for some reason... (the drop). I also imagine the gap is more significant and risky to cyclists than vehicles because more chance of turning sharply towards the gap. Still looking forward to the answer

Answer (score 2):

While this deals with medians and not strictly side barriers, the animal answer is strongly supported by this study:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256425278_Potential_Impacts_of_Highway_Median_Barriers_on_Wildlife_State_of_the_Practice_and_Gap_Analysis

A reasonable response would be that there is a drop into a stream that would prevent animals from crossing.  And I agree, and suspect that simple legality is part of the answer.  A law that requires an animal passing gap every X meters may simply have no exceptions for areas where terrain would be impassable for the animals.